# Get SHA-256 in C#

Tags: c#, java, c#-3.0

I am converting my Java code to C#. I am not able to convert the following function from Java to C#. The fumction is calling the Update method twice. I have tried the C# code in following manner

```
SHA256 sh = SHA256.Create();
            Encoding shEncoding = Encoding.UTF7;
            byte[] data = shEncoding.GetBytes(sn);
            byte hash = sh.ComputeHash(data);
```

But I don't know how to convert two consecutive update function call in C#.

```
String getSHA(byte[] sf,String sn,byte[] mac) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(sf);
        md.update(sn.getBytes());
        byte[] hash = md.digest(mac);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(byte b : hash) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }


       return sb.toString();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Your help/guidance will help me lot.

Comment: You need to look at what that `MessageDigest.update` method does in Java, and replicate it in C#. The `ComputeHash` method in C# operates on the provided input each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` on SHA256 (~`update` and `digest` in Java) and retrieve the hash using the `Hash` property.